# How to use archive be more than 20 MB when I create AWS codeCommit via AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit

I want create a new git repository (AWS codeCommit) with any source from a zip file.

I follow AWS official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codecommit-repository-code.html) but I do not find any restriction (20 MB).

**Cloudformation:**

```
  MyCodeCommit:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Sub ${StackName}-myrepo-codecommit
      RepositoryDescription: This is a repository for the myApp part.
      Code:
        S3:
          Bucket: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}-${StackName}-myApp-source"
          Key: "myApp.zip"
```

I have this error:

```
Code archive supplied cannot be more than 20 MB compressed
```

Is it possible to configure this with more than 20 MB?

Comment: Probably this is a hard limit.

Comment: @Marcin, you can post this ansered, my source have an dependancy error. thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a reference for this limit. So I wouldn't like to make the answer without any support.